# Simple NET6 C++/CLR library cannot be used from NET6 console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, c++-cli

I'm attempting to wrap some native C++ code in a C++/CLI (CLR) library (`TestClrLibrary.NetCore`) in order to use it from a NET6 application.  Everything built fine, and I was able to reference my library from another project (NET6 application) in the same solution.  However, when I run the application, I always get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TestClrLibrary.NetCore, Version=1.0.8252.18682, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'TestClrLibrary.NetCore, Version=1.0.8252.18682, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at TestConsole.NetCore.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I'm using VS2022, and created both projects with default settings for NET6.  The header/source for the library look like this:

```
// TestClrLibrary.NetCore.h
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace TestClrLibraryNetCore {
    public ref class TestClass
    {
    public:
        void Open(System::String^ authority);
    };
}
```

```
// TestClrLibrary.NetCore.cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include "TestClrLibrary.NetCore.h"

namespace TestClrLibraryNetCore {
    void TestClass::Open(System::String^ authority)
    {

    }
}
```

The NET6 console application:

```
// Program.cs
namespace TestConsole.NetCore
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new TestClrLibraryNetCore.TestClass();
            test.Open("arg0");

            Console.WriteLine($"Created test object.");
        }
    }
}
```

The library doesn't actually do anything at this point, and it has no references beyond what are created when Visual Studio creates the project.  The library build settings definitely use the `/clr:netcore` switch, and `TargetFramework` for both projects is `net6.0`.  Both are `x64`, so I know that matches (the usual cause of errors like these).

This does seem to be a .Net Core / NET6 issue, because I can recreate both library & console exe projects targeting `.Net Framework 4.8` and run the resulting application with no issues.

Is there something I'm missing?  What does it take to get the simplest imaginable C++/CLR library built for use in a NET6 application?

Comment: Wow, I get an internal compiler error attempting to build your example. cl /std:c+17 /W4 /clr:netcore .\TestClrLibrary.NetCore.cpp Leads to TestClrLibrary.NetCore.cpp
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0.30319\system.runtime.dll: fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1693)

Comment: @jschroedl  Interesting.  I tried your `cl` command just now and got the same result.  I have no issues building in VS2022, though.

Comment: I'll give it a try within VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several months later, I came back to this project.  After updating Visual Studio 2022 to version 17.5.2 and moving from net6 to net7, it started working.

This isn't a very satisfying answer, as I never did figure out why net6 didn't work.  But, at least any of the dozen or so people using C++/CLR/CLI will know how to keep their work rolling forward.

EDIT:  Just out of curiosity, I decided to install the latest net6 version (6.0.15) and take another run at c++/clr in net6.  It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I created a VS project with your source and a C# console project with your source. I added a reference to the library from the console app and hit a build error about being unable to mix different versions of MSIL.

I consulted a working project I have and the difference was in the .vcxproj settngs for the library. I needed to change the `<TargetFramework>` value from `net6.0` to `net6.0-windows`.  With this change, I was able to build and run your example:

`<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>`

Note, that I could not build the Program.cs from the VS 2022 PowerShell b/c csc.exe there targets .NET Framework. I could *maybe* find an incantation with `dotnet build` but didn't go there...

Hope this helps.

Comment: It makes sense that a CLR project would need to target `net6.0-windows`, as CLR is still a Windows-only thing (as far as I know).  However, I still get the same `could not load file or assembly` error, even after completely cleaning & rebuilding the solution. This gives me another path to investigate, so definitely helpful.  Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Forgot to mention:  First, I changed the `TargetFramework` of just the library project.  Then, I tried both library & console exe projects - same result.

Comment: Probably silly but can you confirm that all the binaries are in the output dir? ex. for my test I see: ConsoleApp1.exe, ConsoleApp1.dll (wtf?), TestClrLibrary.dll and Ijwhost.dll are all in the output dir.

Comment: Good question.  In my console app's output folder, I see:  Ijwhost.dll, TestClrLibrary.NetCore.(dll, pdb), and TestConsole.NetCore.(dll, exe, pdb, deps.json, runtimeconfig.json).  Agreed on the 'wtf'.  Having both dll & exe output for the main application is new to me...must be a NET Core/5/6 thing.

Comment: About your "unable to mix different versions of MSIL" issue:  Are both projects set to the same platform in the Build Configuration?  Both x64, or x86, or whatever?  I did have to set those.

Comment: Yes, I built and ran the x64 Debug config for both.

Comment: I worked on other projects for a few months and came back to it.  After updating VS and moving to net7, it magically worked.  Thanks for taking a crack at it.